# Поиск в ArrayList

Tags: java

Написал метод который должен по ключу искать подходящее значение в ArrayList. Но то ли они разного типа(хотя и String и Object пробовал), то ли я ещё чего-то не замечаю.Возвращает всегда Invalid Key. Подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: Значение]

```
String keys="Comment";
    Object findValue=parser.findByKey(parserJson, keys);


public Object findByKey(ArrayList<JSONElement> parserJson, String findKey) {
    Object findValue = "Invalid key";
    for (int index = 0; index < parserJson.size(); index++) {
        if (parserJson.get(index).key == findKey) {
            findValue=parserJson.get(index).value;
            System.out.println(findValue);
        }
    }
    return findValue;       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема в `parserJson.get(index).key == findKey` знаке ==. вы должны использовать `parserJson.get(index).key.equals(findKey)`, чтобы сравнивать значения, а не ссылки

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: если ответ помог вам решить проблему, то можно выбрать его, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.